# error E: Failed to stat /var/lib/apt/lists/partial while update ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apt, updates

How to fix this error while updating..

```
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to stat /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/id.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_InRelease - pkgAcqTransactionItem::TransactionState-stat (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to stat /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/id.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_main_binary-amd64_Packages - pkgAcqTransactionItem::TransactionState-stat (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to stat /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/id.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_main_binary-i386_Packages - pkgAcqTransactionItem::TransactionState-stat (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to stat /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/id.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_main_i18n_Translation-en - pkgAcqTransactionItem::TransactionState-stat (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to stat /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/id.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_main_dep11_Components-amd64.yml.gz - pkgAcqTransactionItem::TransactionState-stat (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to stat /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/id.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_main_dep11_icons-64x64.tar.gz - pkgAcqTransactionItem::TransactionState-stat (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to stat /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/id.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_restricted_binary-amd64_Packages - pkgAcqTransactionItem::TransactionState-stat (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to stat /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/id.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_restricted_binary-i386_Packages - pkgAcqTransactionItem::TransactionState-stat (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to stat /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/id.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_restricted_i18n_Translation-en - pkgAcqTransactionItem::TransactionState-stat (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to stat /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/id.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_restricted_dep11_Components-amd64.yml.gz - pkgAcqTransactionItem::TransactionState-stat (2: No such file or directory)
```

Answer (score 8):

Run:

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

And re-run:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Fix the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

'sudo apt-get clean'  did not work for my case .

My 'sudo apt-get update' threw out some message like
E: Failed to stat /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/packages.microsoft.com_repos_edge_dists_stable_InRelease - pkgAcqTransactionItem::TransactionState-stat (2: No such file or directory)

I fixed that via
'sudo apt-get purge microsoft-edge-beta'

The point is, if 'sudo apt-get clean' does not work, then 'sudo apt-get purge' may help further.  You need to figure out what packages caused the errors and then purge them.